# "→"-Character in Office 2013 Excel VBA not copyable into Code

Tags: vba, excel, character, imacros

I'm currently programming a VBA Code for iMacros,
therefore I need to have the following string:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON:SUBMIT ATTR=TXT:Find<SP>Facebook<SP>ID<SP>→
```

but, if I copy this code into the VBA Code Editor in Excel 2013, I get the following:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON:SUBMIT ATTR=TXT:Find<SP>Facebook<SP>ID<SP>?
```

The character `→` is not readable for VBA and rewrites it as a `?`

I would use the string like this in my code, to send it to iMacros:

```
  macro = macro + "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON:SUBMIT ATTR=TXT:Find<SP>Facebook<SP>ID<SP>→" + vbNewLine
```

How can I still send the right string to iMacros?

I tried to add the character as a Hexadecimal number to add it to the string, but didn't figure really out how it could work..

Do you have any idea how I can use the character `→` in VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use:

```
macro = macro + "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON:SUBMIT ATTR=TXT:Find<SP>Facebook<SP>ID<SP>" & ChrW(8594) & vbNewLine
```

;)

Hint: The "compiler" simply does not support double byte characters (still they can be inside a string). And `ChrW(8594)` is `→`. If you get problems with other chars, you can use `?AscW(Range(#))` (# is the cell that has that character at the first position) to get the code for `ChrW()` to recreate it.